# change values in a list - python

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
a=[['a','b','c'],['a','f','c'],['a','c','d']]    
for x in a:    
    for y in x:    
        if 'a' in x:    
            x.replace('a','*')`
```

but the result is:

```
a=[['a','b','c'],['a','f','c'],['a','c','d']]
```

and bot `a=[['b','c'],['f','c'],['c','d']]`

What should I do so the changes will last?

Comment: Also, your code is wrong. You wouldn't get any result at all, because it raises `AttributeError`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove all occurrences of `'a'` from all nested sublists, you could do:

```
>>> [[i for i in x if i != 'a'] for x in a]
[['b', 'c'], ['f', 'c'], ['c', 'd']]
```

if you want to replace them with asterisk:

```
>>> [[i if i != 'a' else '*' for i in x] for x in a]
[['*', 'b', 'c'], ['*', 'f', 'c'], ['*', 'c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't about the list.  Python strings are immutable:

```
> a = 'x'
> a.replace('x', 'bye')
> a
'x'
```

You're replacing 'a' with '*' and then throwing away the result.

Try something like:

```
for i,value in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = value.replace('x', 'y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want to replace the element in the nested list, like so:

```
a=[['a','b','c'],['a','f','c'],['a','c','d']]    
for row in a:
   for ix, char in enumerate(row):
       if char == 'a':
           row[ix] = '*'
```

With the result:

```
a = [['*', 'b', 'c'], ['*', 'f', 'c'], ['*', 'c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the function [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
```

> **Return a copy** of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the
>   first count occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
a=[['a','b','c'],['a','f','c'],['a','c','d']]
for x in a:    
    for y in x:    
        if y == 'a':
            x.remove(y)
```

Or even simpler:

```
y = 'a'
a=[['a','b','c'],['a','f','c'],['a','c','d']]
for x in a:    
    x.remove(y)
```

Which gives you `a=[['b','c'],['f','c'],['c','d']]`.

Note: See the documentation on remove() for lists [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[['a','b','c'],['a','f','c'],['a','c','d']]
b=[[subelt.replace('a','*') for subelt in elt] for elt in a]
print(b)

# [['*', 'b', 'c'], ['*', 'f', 'c'], ['*', 'c', 'd']]
```